# LLVM ERROR: Expected a constant shift amount

Tags: rust, arduino-uno, atmel

I'm trying to build Rust for an Arduino UNO. The spec sheet of the device can be found here: https://docs.arduino.cc/resources/datasheets/A000066-datasheet.pdf

I'm trying to compile a simple program at: https://github.com/avr-rust/blink

I run the following commands before building:

```
rustup override set nightly
```

and

```
export AVR_CPU_FREQUENCY_HZ=16000000
```

to set the desired environment.

Then I run the following command to build for the board:

```
cargo build -Z build-std=core --target avr-atmega328p.json --release
```

The `avr-atmega328p.json` file is included at the root level.

However I'm faced with the following error:

```
..
   Compiling adler v1.0.2
   Compiling rustc-demangle v0.1.21
LLVM ERROR: Expected a constant shift amount!
error: could not compile `compiler_builtins` (lib)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It's not enough to link to an external Github repository, you need to include the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem _in the question here_.

Comment: Have you tried to compile an empty program? Since `compiler_builtins` is failing, I'd expect the error is unrelated to your code, and a program with no dependencies and no code (an empty `main()`) would still trigger it.

Comment: something wrong with isa configuration used to create toolchain. That line in compiler which produces this message  commented as "should be unreachable". It's screened by a compile-time known constant. Perhaps  incomplete, bugged support or unsupported device? That's question to devs.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The problem still persists with an empty main. I just used the hello world example provided in the repo.

Comment: @Jmb Sure, if you clone the repo and run these steps, it'll reproduce the problem. I can list all steps and files one by one if needed, but the repo is all that one needs to reproduce it.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Using `nightly-2022-07-10` does work for me (the default for `Rahix/avr-hal-template`) but I would like to use a more recent nightly or stable toolchain.

Comment: There is a discussion about the issue here: https://github.com/rust-lang/compiler-builtins/issues/523